# Azure DevOps Work Item Type Condition for Notifications

Tags: azure, tfs

I created a notification setup in Azure DevOPs to receive a notification every time there is an update about bugs. Now we started working with test plans as well in the same platform, and I get notifications every time a test plan is updated. I tried to limit the notifications to bugs, but unsuccessfully. I tried added a clause to the notification condition such as Work Item Type Contains "Bug", but it doesn't work.
How can I limit the notifications I receive to a specific type of work items?

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT, I tried first the = operator, but I still received notifications about test plans. Since it didn't work, I tried the Contains operator, with no luck either.

Comment: Any update? Someone from microsoft?
When the condition is about "Work Iten Type", there is no values combo box in the value field, The screen shot in the first answer is probably taken from Query screen, not from the Notifications screen. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I limit the notifications I receive to a specific type of work items?

You could try to set the Work Item Type equals Bug Work item.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT, I tried first the = operator, but I still received notifications about test plans. Since it didn't work, I tried the Contains operator, with no luck either.